# Database design for multiple ordered component types on a page

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am creating a page type in the database that would represent a page on a website. The problem is that each page could have multiple components such as: text, image, video, audio file, etc.

I am having trouble with wrapping my head around how that should be represented in the database. The easiest way I can think of is having a table called component as follows:

```
component
=========
id (PK)
page_id (FK)
component_position_on_page (the order each component appears on the page)
text
image
video
audio
bgcolor
fgcolor
```

Now, while that might be the easiest way it has two problems: Most of those fields would be empty because if you choose to place text in a component of a page then the other three component types (image, video, audio) will be empty. It would also not be very scalable if I want to later add other component types.

A better way might be to have a separate table for each of the component types, but then it seems more difficult to link to them and order them correctly on the page.

What is a good way to implement such a design?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are trying to BUILD instead of BUY?  example:  Oracle Users would probably be better off using Oracle Application Express (APEX) ($0) for such a requirement.  (besides - my answer would be based on APEX's design)

Comment: @MichaelKutz Yes, there are many reasons. One of the biggest reason would be vendor lock-in. A second would be increased management needed for it. Right now my preference would be to use MySQL but I also want to be able to migrate away from it in the future if I so choose.